# Vishnu & Brahma worshiped Shiva in which cremation grounds (Shamshan Ghat) for 16000 years?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma, shaivism, agamas

Shiva's supremacy was established after the Fiery Linga incident and he commanded Vishnu & Brahma to worship him using the Agamas. [They did so for sixteen thousand years. Skanda Purana 1.3b.16.62](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370669.html) :-

> **Viṣṇu and Brahmā wore matted hair and applied sacred ash over their bodies.**

So where did they get this sacred ash from? Did they only stay in one cremation ground or multiple ones? Which ones were these?

*EDIT - if it was in South India as one person says, please give any reference. Doesn't have to be from sacred scripture only. Can be from some book, show etc.*

Comment: I think it's not mentioned (at least here) that they worshipped Shiva in cremation grounds. The chapter is about Arunachala so the place must be it. And where did they get scared ash? isn't much relevant because they both are part of Trimurti so it wasn't a great deal for them .We can't expect mention of each and every minute detail in texts as a believer one must assume some things.

Comment: Yes, it is the sacred ash from the cremation ground. This place is in Arunachala, Tiruvannamalai. There is a festival celebrated on the day after Shivaratri on this cremation ground.

Comment: @GIRIBLR Please answer the question if you can!

Comment: It is a local custom and famous festival in the town. But where will I get a scripture supporting this festival in English?

Comment: @GIRIBLR Thank you !! That's very interesting !! It's okay even if you get news reports or something it's good enough for me... I don't know if it will be good enough for moderators though:( Scriptures in Sanskrit etc. are also fine and can be translated

Comment: Local traditions should also be acceptable as they are living scriptures. As long as we have documented references.